# Custom vector shape markers in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, vector, openlayers-3

I have a OpenLayers 3 map on which I'm showing all kinds of data. One of them is showing boats that are detected by a nearby radar. Currently I'm displaying boats as a simple vector Circle. I'd like to display it as a vector shaped as a boat.

As far as I'm informed, my best bet is using a *.png icon, and doing something like this:

```
style: new ol.style.Icon({
  image: new ol.style.Icon(({
    anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
    opacity: 1,
    scale: 1,
    src: '/Content/images/boat.png',
    rotation: 0
  }))
});
```

This works but I'd like to have a vector that doesn't scale when i zoom in/out. My current solution for some different data is displaying a rectangle, but it scales when zooming:

```
var style = (function () {
  function (feature, resolution) {
  // font size
  if (resolution > 0.4) var fontSize = '12px';
  else var fontSize = '14px';

  var temperature = feature.get('temperature') || '-';
  temperature = temperature.replace(/,/g, '.');

  return [new ol.style.Style({
    fill: fill,
    stroke: stroke,
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      font: 'bold ' + fontSize + ' helvetica,sans-serif',
      text: Math.round(temperature * 100) / 100 + '°C',
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: '#000' })
    }),
    geometry: function (feature) {
      var startingCoordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
      var coordinates = [[
          [startingCoordinates[0] + 0, startingCoordinates[1] + 0],
          [startingCoordinates[0] + 33, startingCoordinates[1] + 0],
          [startingCoordinates[0] + 33, startingCoordinates[1] + (-11.35)],
          [startingCoordinates[0] + 0, startingCoordinates[1] + (-11.35)],
          [startingCoordinates[0] + 0, startingCoordinates[1] + 0]
      ]];

      return new ol.geom.Polygon(coordinates);
      }
    })]
  }
})()
```

Is there a better solution for this than using startingCoordinates + (constant * resolution)? Are there any significant performance differences in using vector vs. png? Thanks

**EDIT:** After consulting with few colleagues of mine, I'm basically trying to have this http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/regularshape.html but with a custom shape.

**EDIT2:** Actually more like this http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/graphic-name.html 'The named symbols "lightning", "rectangle" and "church" are user defined.'

Comment: What's the problem with using an icon? The size of icons is specified in pixels. That size doesn't change when zooming in or out. So I do not understand why you mean by "This works but I'd like to have a vector that doesn't scale when i zoom in/out".

Comment: Well, using icons is one possible solution, but then I have to make lots of icons for different kinds of objets and different colors for their states. With programatically generated vector icons I'm able to change their color depending if they are in danger or if they are possible danger for someone else. Also, I'd really like to know more about ol3 and I'm sure there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: @erilem Added a (probably) better explanation if you're interested.

Comment: Regarding performance: from my experience, the difference between raster icons and vector markers becomes significant when rendering thousands of markers. Of course this may vary depending on the client machine. Regarding your question about using non-scalable svg - i solved this by generating an .svg file for each marker. It can be done by a script, but all the markers have to be stored somewhere, so it is only a partial solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but answering for others as this was the top result while I was looking into how to do this.

My solution is to use a data:image/svg+xml with an svg to provide an icon you can programmatically generate

```
new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
        // svg of an equilateral triangle 25px wide at the base
        src: `data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="21.65" width="25" id="canvas"><polygon points="0,0 25,0 12.5,21.65" style="fill:rgba(0,0,0,1);"></polygon></svg>')}`,
    }),
})
```

Note: you [don't need to base64](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) encode svg in a data url but you do need to encodeURIComponent() it for non webkit browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've done it, its similar to the original but without me having to work out what the coordinates should be, I just provide how big by pixels it is and let the map calculate the rest.

```
geometry: function (feature) {
    var startingCoordinates =feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(startingCoordinates);
    var p1,p2,p3,p4,polyCoords=[],sizex=90, sizey=30;
    p1 = pixel;
    p2 = [pixel[0]+sizex,p1[1]];
    p3 = [pixel[0]+sizex,pixel[1]+sizey];
    p4 = [pixel[0],pixel[1]+sizey];
    var p = [p1,p2,p3,p4,p1];
    for (var c = 0; c < 5;c++){
        polyCoords.push(map.getCoordinateFromPixel(p[c]));
    }

    return new ol.geom.Polygon([polyCoords]);
}
```

this gives me a rectangle, which is what I wanted.